# Kivy: How select directory by FileChooser without kv language?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

In [Kivy manual](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html) is example for using FileChooser with kivy language. I want to use FileChooser only in python code. When I mark directory by mouse,  press button *Select Dir* and actually value is in variable *FileChooser.path*. Selection without using this button has not result.
In kv file from example is used event *on_selection*, I binded this event with my function, but without effect.

My questions:

1. How do I get value to path with only mouse using?
2. Which class use event *on_selection*?

Thank You!

```
class Explorer(BoxLayout):   
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Explorer,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.fichoo = FileChooserListView(size_hint_y = 0.8)
        self.add_widget(self.fichoo)

        control   = GridLayout(cols = 5, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=35, size_hint_y = 0.14)
        lbl_dir   = Label(text = 'Folder',size_hint_x = None, width = 80)
        self.tein_dir  = TextInput(size_hint_x = None, width = 350)
        bt_dir = Button(text = 'Select Dir',size_hint_x = None, width = 80)
        bt_dir.bind(on_release =self.on_but_select)

        self.fichoo.bind(on_selection = self.on_mouse_select)

        control.add_widget(lbl_dir)
        control.add_widget(self.tein_dir)
        control.add_widget(bt_dir)

        self.add_widget(control)

        return

    def on_but_select(self,obj):
        self.tein_dir.text = str(self.fichoo.path)
        return

    def on_mouse_select(self,obj):
        self.tein_dir.text = str(self.fichoo.path)
        return

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        self.tein_dir.text = str(self.fichoo.path)
    return super().on_touch_up(touch)
        return super().on_touch_up(touch)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few changes need to be done.

There's no such event `on_selection`, there's property [selection](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController.selection) in `FileChooserListView`. You [can use functions](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-on-propname) `on_<propname>` inside class that has these property, but when you use bind, you should use only `bind(<propname>=`.

Second thing is that by default as you can see in the doc `selection` contains list of selected files, not directories. To make directories actually selctable, you should change [dirselect](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController.dirselect) property to `True`.

Last on is `on_mouse_select` signature: property fires with it's value, you should count that.

Summary changes are:

```
self.fichoo.dirselect = True
self.fichoo.bind(selection = self.on_mouse_select)

# ... and

def on_mouse_select(self, obj, val):
```

After that you would be do the same as with button.

---

If you want to fill input with not actually path you're in, but selected path, you can do following:

```
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if self.fichoo.selection:
        self.tein_dir.text = str(self.fichoo.selection[0])
    return super().on_touch_up(touch)
```

Comment: @Thanks! I really manage processing variables 'path' and 'selection' by two functions type ‘on_<propname>’.